# using for loops to determine difference between each element in an array

Tags: python, physics

[The equation I've been struggling with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGXiz.png)

I already have two arrays- theta and the time t. Both lines are the difference between each data point in the array. The top line being the difference in the angle theta between each data point in the array, and the bottom line is the difference between each data point of time in the array.

Here's my failed attempt at the code:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t,theta = np.loadtxt("theta vs t.txt",unpack=True, skiprows=1)

dt = 0.005 # difference between each element in the time array

t_max=25.00 

n=int(t_max/dt)



for i in range(0,n):    

    theta1= (theta[i+1])-(theta[i])
    t1 = (t[i+1]-t[i])
    omega = theta1/t1


    plt.plot(omega,theta)
```

and here's the error message that comes up

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

[The equation I've been struggling with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGXiz.png)

Comment: Fix that formatting

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your values, let's say `x`, given as a vector resp. array you can access `x(i)` and `x(i-1)` by shifting your vector to the left. By doing this the first element becomes the second, the second becomes the third etc. However, the result vector containing the shifted data (call it `x_shift`) would have a 'gap' at its first element.

Shifting could be done by hand or you could use a ready-to-use-function like [scipy's `shift` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.shift.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift

x = np.arange(0, 10)
x_shift = shift(x, 1)

print(x)
print(x_shift)
```

which prints:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0]
```

As mentioned, shifting generates a gap at the first element which is filled with `0` by default. If you compare both vectors you can see that `x(i)` and `x(i-1)` are right below each other. This means that the desired values have the same indices and we should be able to calculate the difference `x(i) - x(i-1)` by calling `x - x_shift`. However, since the last value of the shifted vector is filled up with `0` the difference of the two vectors is not correct at this last element, so just ignore it by applying `result[:-1]`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift

x = np.arange(0, 10)
x_shift = shift(x, -1)

result = x - x_shift
result = result[:-1]

print(result)
```

As an alternative we could use [numpy's `roll` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) which is very similar to a shift. Instead of filling up missing data with a given value, `roll` 'flips' data falling out at one end of the vector and inserts it at the other one. Using `roll` is basically the same:

```
import numpy as np

# generate some sample values
theta_values = np.arange(0, 15)
omega_values = np.arange(15, 30)

# shift values to left
theta_shift = np.roll(theta_values, 1)
omega_shift = np.roll(omega_values, 1)

# calc difference of omega(i) and omega(i-1)
theta_diff = (theta_values - theta_shift)
omega_diff = (omega_values - omega_shift)

# due to i and i+1 we need to ignore last element
theta_diff = theta_diff[:-1]
omega_diff = omega_diff[:-1]

# calculate fraction of (theta(i) - theta(i-1)) / (omega(i) - (omega(i-1)))
fraction = theta_diff / omega_diff
print(fraction)
```